# python: how to check egress interface

Tags: python-2.7, packet, scapy

I need to send a packet from my python script.
I have a destination ip address.
I need:
- egress interface name which is usually default route (i need it for sniffing response)
- ip address of that interface (i need to use it in my application payload)

How can i do it from python ?

Thanks,

Comment: I know conf.route from scapy - but i would need a lot of code to find out which one to use. I hope to reuse code which is already out there (possibly in scapy).

Comment: LOL egress - is one of those words that non-native English speakers  will never google for :)

Answer (score 2):

[Pynetinfo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynetinfo/) seems to be your best bet. This is a small sample on my machine. Your results will differ, but you will of course have a default gateway.

```
>>> import netinfo
>>> netinfo.get_routes()
({'dest': '0.0.0.0', 'netmask': '0.0.0.0', 'gateway': '192.168.0.1', 'dev': 'wlan1'}, 
{'dest': '169.254.0.0', 'netmask': '255.255.0.0', 'gateway': '0.0.0.0', 'dev': 'wlan1'}, 
{'dest': '192.168.0.0', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'gateway': '0.0.0.0', 'dev': 'wlan1'})
>>> default_gateway = 
...[route for route in netinfo.get_routes() if route['dest'] == '0.0.0.0'][0]
>>> default_gateway['gateway']
'192.168.0.1'
>>> default_gateway['dev']
'wlan1'
```

As for getting the IP address of that interface...

```
>>> import netifaces
>>> netifaces.ifaddresses(default_gateway['dev'])[netifaces.AF_INET]
[{'broadcast': '192.168.0.255', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'addr': '192.168.0.9'}]
```

For getting the interface that a IP packet would use with a given destination, on my Linux system. I'm not sure of another way.

```
>>> dst = "127.0.0.1"
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(["ip", "route", "get", dst], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.stdout.read()
'local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  src 127.0.0.1 \n    cache <local> \n'
```

Comment: thanks, looks nice, but i have many entries in routing table (because of many interfaces and dynamic routing). Default route will not always be selected. Do you know any way to perform route lookup easily to choose the correct routing entry/interface ? (i know destination IP, would need to find best/most specific match entry)

Comment: RyPeck - you are my man :) Thanks - it solves all my problems :)

Comment: I wanted to but do not have 15 reputation points and can not mark it as the answer :(

Comment: You mean vote up. There is a check box beneath the vote up and down arrows that you can use to mark the answer as correct.